# Step by Step: Remove/Sideline Preinstalled Windows 8, Install Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, windows-8, uefi

I want Ubuntu as my primary/only operating system.

Computer came with presumptive Pre-Installed Windows 8.(touch screen)

**Help.** New Dell Inspiron 15r. Cannot install Ubuntu 12.04-03 or LTS.

I need/request **step by step** instructions to **remove** Windows 8 or **sideline** Windows 8.
  (ie) BIOS settings
I need to know:

What to have;
What settings;
When to apply;
Boot manager settings.
UEFI.
Etc.

This should be easy, but I am mired in the **Herpes** that is Microsoft.

I end up having a presumed dual boot that will not access Ubuntu.

(ie)
**Step 1**: Turn on computer.
**Step 2**: F# to change ... to ... at Dell prompt...

I want to use Ubuntu as my primary operating system **or** my only operating system.

Comment: Did you follow the official instructions here? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start fresh just get a "boot cd" it will allow you to totally wipe out the drive and reformat it, to a blank drive. you have to be able to enter the
Basic Input Output System(BIOS) and make changes. Make the drive Active, After that install the OS.
Maybe you would want to save the drive first by doing a sector copy, if you have spare drive. the boot CD has all the stuff you need.